# Why isn't it possible to launch a non-English SE site?

Tags: discussion, area-51, languages

I'd like to launch a site in French:
*https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/125462/transition-ecologique*, but my proposal got blocked by a rule I wasn't aware of (since there exist foreign language SE sites that have been launched through Area 51) and that I don't understand.

Why is this the case, and can it change in the future?

Related questions and summary

- *[A better approach for this foreign language proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102882/a-better-approach-for-this-foreign-language-proposal)* that treats a similar subject. In the comments, I see that the sentence "English is also a foreign language to many of us" received nine upvotes. I would had that Python language math overflows are definitively written in totally different language, and this is not a problem.
- *[What is the status of support for foreign language SEs?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169728/what-is-the-status-of-support-for-foreign-language-ses)*

Comment: Some more links that could be useful (but I don't have exact answers to your questions): https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20988/178611 and https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20987/178611

Comment: I think the second link in Tinkeringbell's comment is the most valid answer. SE needs a CM fluent in the language, and to limit the translation work needed there already needs to be an SO translation in the language you wan't to start a site in. The latter is definetly not the case, the former I don't know.

Comment: @Luuklag also need to make adjustments for RTL languages, and more technical stuff for various language-specific issues. All in all, **lots** of resources to spend.

Comment: @Luuklag I don't think that it would be a problem to launch a site in french with the english interface... I could contribute to the translation if needed. No ressource needed, it is rather an internal policy question.